# Regresar a form anterior

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Teniendo un form principal con un botón con el cual accedo al segundo form, ¿Cómo puedo regresar al form principal al cerrar el segundo mediante el botón de la x?

Form1:

```
private void buttonEnterAdmin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    Login login = new Login();
    login.Show();
}
```

Form2:

```
private void Login_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Main main = new Main();
    main.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el evento FormClosed
Subscribete al evento y puedes abrirlo en el momento que la cierres

Un pequeño ejemplo

```
void SegundaForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
 #Codigo
 Form2 primeraForm = new Form2();
 primeraForm.Show();
}
```

Fuente de documentacion : [Evento FormClosed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed(v=vs.110).aspx)

Si necesitas que el evento se dispare antes de que se Cierre la forma
Utiliza El evento Form.FormClosing
[Evento Form.FormClosing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Ya que el evento de FormClosing tengo entendido se dispara antes que FormClosed

Comment: Ya he intentado de esta manera, pero no me regresa al form1.

Comment: Puedes poner tu codigo Porfavor? @Neon Thanks!

Comment: Ya intentaste Suscribirte al evento Form.FormClosing ?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
Ya que el evento de FormClosing tengo entendido se dispara antes que FormClosed.

Comment: Sí, ahora sí funcionó, gracias.